# SimpleDateFormat parse 2018-11-08_21h34m46sZ

Tags: java, timezone, simpledateformat, utc, datetime-parsing

Hi want to convert UTC times to local time and i am doing this

```
public class TimeZoneN {
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws ParseException {

    String timeStr1 = "2018-11-08_21h34m46sZ";

    String formatStr1 = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH'h'mm'm'ss's'Z";

    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat( formatStr1 );
    formatter.setTimeZone( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "UTC" ) );

    Date date1 = formatter.parse( timeStr1 );
    System.out.println( date1 );

    }
}
```

i am getting a parse exception because od the Z, but when i do

```
String formatStr1 = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH'h'mm'm'ss'sZ'";
```

It passes, is that valid though ? Woudn't that consider sZ as a single constant and not Z as the timezone token ?

Comment: Yes, that's valid. `Z` is a literal.

Comment: In that case what difference would that make if i dont include it at all ? I tried with String formatStr1 = "yyyy-MM-dd_HH'h'mm'm'ss's'"; and its doing exactly the same job.

Comment: `Z` is not a literal, it’s a UTC offset of zero, also known as “Zulu time zone”. You need to parse as an offset or your formatter will assume the time zone of your JVM or the time zone set on the formatter and give you an incorrect result (if that didn’t happen to be UTC).

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd_HH'h'mm'm'ss's'X").parse(timeStr1, Instant::from)` will give you an `Instant` of `2018-11-08T21:34:46Z`.

Comment: It's not a duplicate i am not asking for the same parsing format Ole.

Comment: Sorry, @user2133558. [That other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52480189/parse-date-string-in-java) is asking how to parse `Z` in a date-time string. You are asking how to parse `Z` in a date-time string. I was trying to be helpful. Since you prefer not to see your question as a dupe, I have reopened it.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that `Z` denotes *Zulu time*, another name for UTC. You may also think of it as offset zero from UTC. So you will want to parse `Z` as an offset to ensure that your time is interpreted correctly.

### java.time

However, don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`. It’s notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Don’t use `Date` either, it too is long outdated and it too has design problems.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd_H'h'm'm's's'X");
    String timeStr1 = "2018-11-08_21h34m46sZ";
    Instant instant1 = formatter.parse(timeStr1, Instant::from);
    System.out.println(instant1);
```

Output:

> 2018-11-08T21:34:46Z

For the sake of completeness:

> want to convert … to local time

Taking America/Toronto as a random example:

```
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = instant1.atZone(ZoneId.of("America/Toronto"));
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Output:

> 2018-11-08T16:34:46-05:00[America/Toronto]

In a comment you asked about `Z`:

> what difference would that make if i dont include it at all ?

Two things:

- You want to make sure the string includes the required offset and object if not, or you risk that errors pass unnoticed. It’s called input validation.
- As I mentioned you want to parse `Z` as an offset or you cannot extract an unambiguous point in time from the parsed values.

**Link:** [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.